# Download web files with certificate and key

Tags: python, https, wget, urllib2

I have a wget command with arguments that downloads a file. I'm trying to write a python script that does the same. The args are all required or the file is not downloadable. I prefer urllib2 as i'm on centos7 and it's included with python 2.7. It seems this is possible, but i'm having trouble constructing the code to do so.

```
$ wget --ca-cert=/somedir/company.com.ca.crt --certificate=/somedir/company.com.crt --private-key=/somedir/company.com.key https://company.com/software/product.tar
```

Or easier on the eyes...

```
$ wget 
--ca-cert=/somedir/company.com.ca.crt 
--certificate=/somedir/company.com.crt 
--private-key=/somedir/company.com.key 
https://company.com/software/product.tar
```

How can this wget be put into python using urllib2?

Comment: Request can help for this http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/